# Azure Functions Logging written to the ILogger doesn't appear in Azure Table Storage

Tags: function, azure

I am using `ILogger`(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging) as a log in interface in Azure Functions.

However, logs doesn't appear in Azure Table Storage and Azure Portal.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

        [FunctionName("Function2")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, 
        ILogger log)
    {
        string myname = "jack";
        log.LogInformation("hello, my name is {myname}.", myname);
        //...
```

Is there a way to output to Azure Table Storage using `ILogger`?

[Azure Table Storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwYf6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it possible to output to Azure Table Storage with ILogger, however it does allow output to Application Insights which provides a lot of more tooling around traces like this. Here is a blog post explaining the integration:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/04/06/azure-functions-application-insights/